# Compiled Vim Is Not Using vimrc files

Tags: linux, linux-ubuntu

I compiled Vim 9 from github source https://github.com/vim/vim. I am compiling Vim in Ubuntu 20.04. I tried compiling it according to this [doc](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b74ebfc6bf343ed825b111157261a8d99da6d670/src/INSTALL#L191).

However, I can not get it to read the system file `/etc/vim`. It also does not read `~./vimrc` and does not read `~/.vim/` (contains `colors`, `pack`, `plugins`, etc.) and does not read `~/.vimrc`. It lists them in `vim --version` but it is not showing.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Here are the steps below that I ran:

```
34187  ./configure --prefix=/usr
34188  make distclean
34189  ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gui=gtk 
34190  make VIMRCLOC=/etc VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim MAKE="make -e"
34191  sudo make VIMRCLOC=/etc VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim MAKE="make -e"
34192  make install
34193  sudo make install
```

---

Here is the info:

```
% /usr/local/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Sep 27 2023 09:13:13)
Included patches: 1-1943
Compiled by one@work
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lm -ltinfo -lrt -ldl
```

Comment: I suspect the people that know best are those that package Vim for Linux systems; you might check the debian or arch packages or something like that.

Comment: How do you know it does not read any of the config files you mention? What do you observe? BTW, `sudo make` (not followed by `install`) looks wrong. You should not have to run as root to build your software.

Comment: I followed your link and the commands there have little in common with the ones you show. There's a line that starts with [to build Vim on Ubuntu ...](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b74ebfc6bf343ed825b111157261a8d99da6d670/src/INSTALL#L42). Maybe try with the commands given there?